# Is there a standard about the usage of "()", "[]", "{}" in grammar formula? What does these symbols mean? How do I use them correctly?

Tags: grammar

I was learning some kind of expression. When I searched that in [google](https://www.google.com/search?bih=598&biw=1280&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&hl=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNTL6zRSTrtrRfnQ6VlV95HgqKofRA%3A1581921549773&ei=DTVKXpfWLs_5-gTw6Z2gBA&q=meaning%20of%20%22a%20little%20bit%20adjective%22&oq=meaning%20of%20%22a%20little%20bit%20adjective%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...632243.6206729..6207215...1.4..2.11725.39727.2-2j14j4j1j9-4....2..0....1j2..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j46i199i291i395i275j0i67j46i199i291i395j0j46i322i131i395j0i131i10j46i199i175i395j0i10j46i199i175i10i395j0i273j0i131j46i199i291j46i322i131j35i39j46i322i395j46i322i131i395i275j46i322i395i275j35i362i39j0i30.RI7pyVBKBBs&ved=0ahUKEwjXkKWA_dfnAhXPvJ4KHfB0B0QQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), I got a variety of symbols.

there are 3 main types of symbols

a pair of brackets

> a little bit [adjective]

a pair of parentheses

> (subject) + y u + (extent) + (adjective)

a pair of brackets inside a pair of parentheses

> a little (bit [adjective])

[image]

I also saw a pair of curly braces {} somewhere else, though I cannot find it at this point.

I call this a formula

> subject + verb + adjective

I don't know what it is should be called.

Anyway, some of these formulas use "()", "[]", like the examples above.

I am not asking how to use these symbols in normal english writing, I am asking the usage of these symbols in terms of grammar formula.

In information technology, specifically, in linux command/bash, each of "()", "[]", "{}" has different meaning, for instance (https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html),

> the {} is replaced with each line read from standard input.

So, what does these symbols mean in terms of grammar formula? How do I use them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

When writing English, the only brackets you would normally use are *parenthesis*: **( )**

These are used for enclosing parenthetic statements (a statement that explains or qualifies something) within the text. Like I did just there. You should be able to ignore what is within the parenthesis and the sentence would still be grammatically correct. You can also use commas, a common punctuation mark, for parenthesis. Like that.

*Square brackets* **[ ]** are used to contain parenthetic words or statements added *after* the original text was written, perhaps by another person [such as an editor - Ed] that qualify or explain what has been said.

*Braces* **{ }** are normally only used to contain *number sets*, for example: {1,2,3,4,5}.

These are all examples of their *formal use* in English grammar, and there are possibly some other uses too. Like a lot of other symbols, they have all gained different uses in *computing*, for example in computer programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the OP. Please take a look :) As you mentioned, something in computer programming languages is involved.

Comment: @brennn I've given you the *names* of all the brackets and also their grammar usage, as this is an English language Q&A site. I can't help you with computer programming terminology. Be careful not to steer your question to one of computer programming otherwise it will be considered off topic and deleted.

Comment: Take it easy. The discussion has been limited to english grammar :)

Comment: @brennn I am taking it easy. Hope my answer is helpful to you.